# Class from maven dependency is not listed in eclipse "Open Type"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am having a maven project that has few maven dependencies. Out of those dependencies, there is a custom jar coming from our custom maven repo.

When try to search for the classes from that custom jar using '*Open Type*', I am unable to see the classes. But I see the jar is available under '*Maven Dependencies*' of the project. Also I am able to use the classes from the jar in my project.

**PS:**

- When I run tests from the project I get "`ClassNotFoundException`" for the classes from that Jar. Not sure if there is a relation between this and the issue of eclipse unable to list it in "Open Type".

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: What happens if you double-click the class in _Maven Dependencies_ to open it? Maybe the JAR contains `.java` instead of `.class` files or the `.class` files have a higher version than the used JRE/JDK to run it.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I cannot post the pom as is. Will simplify it to the part related to the jar and post it.

Comment: @howlger 
- The jar contains the .class files.
- The jar is built and published using the same jdk version that is being used in the project.

Comment: These were only two examples of reasons on a question with little information (what JDK, which Eclipse and M4E version do you use, JPMS yes/no, Maven scope, ...?). That's why I asked you, what happens if you double-click the class in _Maven Dependencies_ to open it? If only _Open Type_ does not work, try in _Window > Preferences: Java_ clicking the _Rebuild Index_ button.

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple reasons:

1. try `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
2. try in package explorer